# Someone who stubbornly refuses to talk

Tags: single-word-requests

A situation may arise, for example, when parents refuse to give the child something he asks for. Then the child won't speak to parents unless they try hard to convince him. What is the English word for this behavior? In Hindi/Urdu we call it *roothna*.

If my question is unclear, you could watch this video and give the word for how the Grandmother is acting:

*[Dadi Amma Dadi Amma Maan Jao](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueJRRmVCBiI)*

Comment: The grandmother in the video is definitely sulking.

Comment: I have a feeling I could get much more of what I wanted if I just sang and danced like that...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*[Sulking](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sulk#Verb)*, "expressing ill humor or offense by remaining sullenly silent or withdrawn" is one such word, and to some extent, *[pouting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pout#Verb)*, "to be or pretend to be ill-tempered; sulk".

Comment: I was just looking some videos about pouting. It does not seem to mean that. I think sulking is a better word.

Comment: @RaoufAthar Besides the sense I mentioned, pouting has another sense, "to push out one's lips", which might be what videos are showing.

Comment: @Raouf Athar: It's true that *pouting* also has the sense of "pursing your lips and/or pushing them forward", which in some context is nothing to do with the meaning we're discussing here (young ladies may do it to look sexually inviting, for example). But jwpat7 is quite correct that it *can* be used as a synonym for "sulking" - you might justifiably prefer "sulk", but it's not true to say *pouting...does not...mean that.*

Comment: Just to throw my two cents in... *pouting* is something that children (or adults!) typically do while *sulking*. As a result, the word "pouting" is often used as a substitute for "sulking", even though the one behavior isn't actually the other.

Answer (score 13):

If I understand you correctly, the word is "sulking". This means to refuse to speak to someone because you are unhappy with them. It is normally used when talking about children. If you say an adult is sulking, you are saying that they are not only not speaking but are acting in a childish manner.

Answer (score 13):

*Giving someone the [silent treatment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/silent_treatment)* means pointedly ignoring them and refusing to speak to them; you could say that the child is giving the parents the silent treatment.

Comment: Well it is a kind of Silent Treatment but I am looking for the appropriate word.

Comment: "the silent treatment" makes it absolutely explicit that the child is not talking. "Sulking" covers a range of behaviours, with silence being very likely, but not for definite. A sulking person might, for example, answer questions in short sentences, in a weary or hostile tone.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that the child is "sulking". There's also a much more colloquial (British/Irish?) version that I'd use, where I'd say that the child is "in a strop" or "having a strop".

There's an even more colloquial version ["to get the monk on"](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/48/messages/616.html), which I remember a friend of mine from the North of England used to use. Probably not one for general usage :)

Comment: I think *sulking* is more associated with **silence**, but *strop* suggests a more vocal negative reaction - up to and including a child jumping up and down and screaming, which we would never call *sulking*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's true - a strop can include a range of behaviour up to (and possibly including) a tantrum.